# Countunique if cell in same row in other column is not empty

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to calculate the amount of uniques you have in a column with respect to another value not beeing empty. For example:

```
A    3
B
X    5
Y
A
X    3
Y
```

This should then result in the answer 2 since X should only be counted once even though the cell is not empty for any. So I think I would need a combination of countunique and some if statement. Or if there is a query solution to the issue.

Tried this but I have not used the query function before so I guess I am not writing it correctly:

```
=query('ISK Investeringar'!C1:F72; "select C, countunique(C) where (NOT(F=""))")

Bank    70,98   10,11%  120
Bank    94,62   6,87%   
Bank    143,5   9,90%   
Finans  248,8   3,82%   70
Dagligvaruhandel    209,2   3,35%   
Dagligvaruhandel    439,6   2,62%   
Utdelande ETF   125,72  4,45%   60
Investmentbolag 482,1   2,70%   
Investmentbolag 25,76   1,94%   75
Investmentbolag 269,6   3,06%   
Investmentbolag 205,8   2,79%   40
Investmentbolag 130,1   1,92%
```

For this sample of values I want the formula to return 4 as a value since there is 1 Bank where F is not "", 1 Finans the same, 1 Utdelande ETF also the same and for "Investmentbolag" only one occurance with an F field not "" should be counted so 4 in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resume your example, you can try `COUNTIFS` :

```
=COUNTIFs(A1:A10,"X",B1:B10,"<>")
```

Two conditions :
`A1:A10` must match exactly X
`B1:B10` must be not `blank`

---

Second try :

```
=COUNTIFs(
          unique($A$1:$A$10),
          "<>",
          ArrayFormula(vlookup(unique($A$1:$A$10),sort($A$1:$B$10,2,false),2,false)),
          "<>"
)
```

This count how many unique values in `A:A` have a non empty cell in `B:B` next to them

Edit : Add a `=SORT` to be sure `vlookup` match values.

Comment: Yes I have thought of this aswell, however since I require the "X" to be unique instead. This could work if I took all the unique fields and put them in a column and then wanted to calculate the amount of each field. However what I need is basically a functions that looks if a field is not empty, if that field is not empty and the category has not been counted before then +1. So as a script is it possible, however I want to see if there are any possible querys or functions that can make the same calculation.

Comment: @LuckAss I edited my answer : Is this what you're looking ? else you can add some more example in the original question.
Edit : I just saw this formula has a big  flaw, I'm gonna check for another formula and will update

Comment: Seems to be in the right direction, however this gives me an error stating that the arrays are different sizes. In my case I have Column C and F which are actually used for the calculation.

Comment: `=COUNTIFs( unique($C$1:$C$100), "<>", ArrayFormula(vlookup(unique($C$1:$C$100),sort({$C$1:$C$100,$F$1:$F$100},2,false),2,false)), "<>" )`  You can try this ? else you can share a sheet with dummy data or your formula

Comment: Getting errors in formula interpretation for that formula, I added some dummy values above

Comment: I'm not sure where is the problem, I tried this formula with your data and it returns `4`. You can check it on [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qNVDNIjwci-KybbHAdt6aDAqdd2qYA42pMhpTJcSuQY/edit#gid=0) in cell `H1`. Can you share the formula you are using ? or a sample sheet with the problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100000/discussion-between-luckass-and-pjmg).

Comment: Could you perhaps take a quick look at this post? 
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/136111/incorrect-and-somewhat-strange-results-when-using-countifs-with-arrayformula I use the formula you provided for me with some strange results when modifying it for reading strings.