# Incorrect and somewhat strange results when using COUNTIFs with Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have three functions responsible for checking if I own a stock (by seeing that the column F is not empty) Then I want to check column AB to see what market the stock is from. In the first case I want to calculate the amount of Large Cap companies I own stocks in.

However my formulas seem to recalculate incorrectly. Sometimes they do not change at all when I add new owned stocks on my list. The following three functions are the functions I am using. (Keep in mind that it is European separators so the "`;"` should for example not be changed to "`,`".

```
=COUNTIFs(('ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103); "<>" ; ArrayFormula(vlookup(('ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103);sort({'ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103\'ISK Investeringar'!$AB$3:$AB$103};2;false);2;false)); "Large Cap" )/D3

=(COUNTIFs(('ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103); "<>" ; ArrayFormula(vlookup(('ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103);sort({'ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103\'ISK Investeringar'!$AB$3:$AB$103};2;false);2;false)); "Mid Cap") + COUNTIFs(('ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103); "<>" ; ArrayFormula(vlookup(('ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103);sort({'ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103\'ISK Investeringar'!$AB$3:$AB$103};2;false);2;false)); "Small Cap"))/D3

=COUNTIFs(('ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103); "<>" ; ArrayFormula(vlookup(('ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103);sort({'ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103\'ISK Investeringar'!$AB$3:$AB$103};2;false);2;false)); "First North" )/D3
```

With these 3 formulas and for example with 7 different stocks in the following markets:

```
Large Cap     
Large Cap     
Large Cap     
Large Cap     
ETF
Mid Cap
First North
```

I get the following percentages:

```
71% Large Cap
14% Mid Cap
0% First North
```

Can anyone see what is incorrect in this formula for the purpose described above. I have the same type of formula for looking at how many unique branches I own companies in and that function works perfectly. I will share that function below:

```
=COUNTIFs( UNIQUE('ISK Investeringar'!$C$3:$C$103); "<>"; ArrayFormula(vlookup(unique('ISK Investeringar'!$C$3:$C$103);sort({'ISK Investeringar'!$C$3:$C$103\'ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103};2;false);2;false)); "<>" )
```

So I would like to know why my first 3 formulas is not working correctly but the last one is.

Link to the worksheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gxOsNvpw4iWejj4nzFmOsufIzrbwfqY0jbNhN2HCn4o/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet

Comment: @Tedinoz +1, furthermore I think it's better to use a query because the formulas are getting really complicated and difficult to read.

Comment: @Tedinoz I have added a share link to the sheet now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `query` who count of the occurence in column `A` with non empty data on column `B` :

```
=QUERY(A1:B10;
  "SELECT A,count(B) 
  WHERE NOT B matches '' 
  Group by A 
  label count(B) 'non-empty rows'")
```

[image: Illustration]

---

Example with this formula :

```
=COUNTIFs(
('ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103); ""<>"" ; 
ArrayFormula(vlookup(('ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103);
sort({'ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103\'ISK Investeringar'!$AB$3:$AB$103};2;false);
2;false))
; ""Large Cap"" )/D3
```

Here's a Query that does the same job :

```
=QUERY(
{'ISK Investeringar'!$F$3:$F$103\'ISK Investeringar'!$AB$3:$AB$103};
"SELECT Col1,count(Col2) 
WHERE NOT Col2 matches '' AND Col1 = 'Large Cap' 
Group by Col1 
Label count(Col2) 'non-empty rows' "
)/D3
```

Comment: This query function seems to throw me an error on line 5 column 1. QUERY parametern 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " ")" ") "" at line 5, column 1. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "format" ... "options" ... "," ... Huge thanks for all your help, now and previously :)

Comment: I forgot to close the  SQL statement with `"`

Comment: Big thanks, this solution works perfectly when switching Col1 and Col2 in the formula. Huge thanks, you save my day yet again sir.